# Using Websites inside a jar in with WebView JavaFX

Tags: html, javafx, webview, jar, javafx-webengine

I created a simple Application in JavaFX which copies an fxml and some Websites into a res Folder. The fxml is in res/gui and the websites are in res/szenario.

When im running my code from my IDE the GUI shows up an the embedded WebView shows the Websites and i can click through them. 
But if build a jar File the Websites are not shown properly. The are missing styles and logic. I cant click on the Buttons in the WebView for example.

Here is my Code of the MainController:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML 
    private WebView browser_id;
    WebEngine webEngine;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        webEngine = browser_id.getEngine();

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                jsobj.setMember("jsCallback", new JavaScriptCallback());
            }
        });

        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/res/szenario/home.html").toExternalForm());
    }

}
```

The GUI is loaded by using:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/res/gui/main.fxml"));
```

Why is the fxml working in the jar and the websites are not?

**Edit**:
I added an image of the `res` folder which contains the GUI and websites:

[image: Project structure preview]

Comment: Does your html reference some resources using a relative url such as `../images/home.png`.  If so, that may not work because `..` does not resolve using the jar file protocol.  However, absolute urls likely will resolve ok.  Perhaps if you supply some minimal html and resources in an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue, it may be easier to assist.

Comment: I added a image of the res folder. Hopefully that helps understanding my issue. What is an absolute url?

Comment: I guess [absolute url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676525(v=vs.85).aspx) is a slightly wrong terminology for this as you wouldn't want to explicitly use a .  What I mean is a location that begins with a `/` and does not contain any `..` characters.  Beginning with `/` is probably not required, but not using `..` definitely is.  Anyway it is difficult to assist without the information requested in the previous comment.